# How to simulate a data exception with localdb

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, localdb

I'm using a LocalDB database with EntityFramework on an ASP.NET MVC project.

How can I simulate a connection failure to test the following try...catch block?

```
try
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      db.Entry(course).State = EntityState.Modified;
      db.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
}
catch (DataException)
{

   ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes.");
}
```

I've tried trying to take the database offline in SQL management studio, but it just hangs.  I can't stop the SQL service as LocalDB doesn't run as a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried giving it a non-existing name of LocalDB instance? Just put this in your connection string for this test:

```
Server=(localdb)\missing_instance`
```

(if you embed this connection string in code don't forget to escape the `\` character :-))

```
connectionString="Server=(localdb)\\missing_instance;..."
```

Answer (score 1):

You can stop a LocalDB instance even though it doesn't run as a service, you can use the SQLLocalDB.exe tool to do this:

[SqlLocalDB Utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212961.aspx)

Comment: Except everytime I stop the instance, and then run my code, LocalDB starts back up again...!